# Setup C# TFTP server using GSF.NET library

Tags: c#

I am trying to setup a TFTP server in C#. I  am using this library https://www.gridprotectionalliance.org/NightlyBuilds/GridSolutionsFramework/Help/html/N_GSF_Net_TFtp.htm.

```
using GSF.Net.TFtp;
using System.Net;

IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.102");
TFtpServer tftpserver = new TFtpServer(ip);
tftpserver.Start();
```

When I run that code the program exits inmediately. It seems I need to listen to an event to do something.

```
D:\TFTPtest\TFTPtest\bin\Release\net6.0\TFTPtest.exe (process 17884) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

The API says:

```
public delegate void TFtpServerEventHandler(
    ITFtpTransfer transfer,
    EndPoint client
)
```

The API don't give examples on how to do that.

An example of how to do that, how to setup the eventhandler, would be great.

PS: I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: Are you running this in a service ? Or just some console app ? Some more context is needed.. Are you subscribing to the deleagate anywhere ?

Comment: Just a console app.

Comment: Okay, im not familiar with this particular package, but they offer a delegate you need to subscribe to.. So it will fire the event and your subscription process it..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events
To be fair their documentation seems very thin.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a service project to run, it sounds like you have a problem with the console app itself automatically closing - code 0 just means it finished.. This is normal, just means there is nothing else to do. if you want to test it you can do `while(true) { tftpserver.Start(); }` - Note - only for test

Comment: `OnReadRequest` event by the looks of it https://www.gridprotectionalliance.org/NightlyBuilds/GridSolutionsFramework/Help/html/E_GSF_Net_TFtp_TFtpServer_OnReadRequest.htm

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to handle the events:

```
using GSF.Net.TFtp;
using System.Net;


namespace Tftp.Net.SampleServer
{
class Program
{
    private static String? ServerDirectory;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ServerDirectory = "D:\\Prgramacion\\Tftproot";

        TFtpServer tftpserver = new TFtpServer();
        Console.WriteLine(tftpserver.ToString());
        tftpserver.OnReadRequest += new TFtpServerEventHandler(server_OnReadRequest);
    
        tftpserver.Start();
        Console.Read();
        
    }
 
    static void server_OnReadRequest(ITFtpTransfer transfer, EndPoint client)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Reading...");

    String path = Path.Combine(ServerDirectory, transfer.Filename);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

        //Is the file within the server directory?
        if (!file.FullName.StartsWith(ServerDirectory, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            CancelTransfer(transfer, TFtpErrorPacket.AccessViolation);
        }
        else if (!file.Exists)
        {
            CancelTransfer(transfer, TFtpErrorPacket.FileNotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            OutputTransferStatus(transfer, "Accepting request from " + client);
            StartTransfer(transfer, new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        }

    }

    private static void StartTransfer(ITFtpTransfer transfer, Stream stream)
    {
        transfer.OnProgress += new TFtpProgressHandler(transfer_OnProgress);
        transfer.Start(stream);
    }
    static void transfer_OnProgress(ITFtpTransfer transfer, TFtpTransferProgress progress)
    {
        OutputTransferStatus(transfer, "Progress " + progress);
    }
    private static void CancelTransfer(ITFtpTransfer transfer, TFtpErrorPacket reason)
    {
        OutputTransferStatus(transfer, "Cancelling transfer: " + reason.ErrorMessage);
        transfer.Cancel(reason);
    }

    static void transfer_OnError(ITFtpTransfer transfer, TftpTransferError error)
    {
        OutputTransferStatus(transfer, "Error: " + error);
    }

    static void transfer_OnFinished(ITFtpTransfer transfer)
    {
        OutputTransferStatus(transfer, "Finished");
    }

    static void transfer_OnProgress(ITFtpTransfer transfer, TftpTransferProgress progress)
    {
        OutputTransferStatus(transfer, "Progress " + progress);
    }

    private static void OutputTransferStatus(ITFtpTransfer transfer, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + transfer.Filename + "] " + message);
    }
}
}
```

This was based in the example of another library:

https://github.com/Callisto82/tftp.net/blob/master/Tftp.Net.SampleServer/Program.cs

Edit: I added the full code for reading a file from a TFTP Client.